# ElasticSearch instance not visible inside network on Windows [7.3.1]

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

I am trying to install an ElasticSearch instance on a Windows Server, and the idea is to be consumed by applications inside the domain network. Until know I have configured the elasticsearch.yml:

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: testcluster
http.port: 9200
network.host: _site_
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
- SERVERTEST
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: SERVERTEST
path.data: D:\ElasticSearch\data
path.logs: D:\ElasticSearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

If I try to connect inside the server from the url http://SERVERTEST:9200/ I can access without any problem, but I can't access from another computer inside the same network.

Am I missing something? or it is something that I have to configure on the firewall or anywhere else?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, was a mistake configuring the firewall port on Windows firewall.

It was fixed just configuring the TCP port 9200 properly